# PHP8 extension could not be loaded (all)

Tags: php, windows-10, apache2.4

I build up a new development Windows with:

Windows 10 Prof. -
Apache 2.4.54 -
PHP 8.1.7

The problem is that PHP could not load the extension (it does not matter which one I activate).
Configuration in php.ini

```
extension_dir = "ext"

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
extension=curl
extension=mbstring
extension=openssl
```

In the apache Log throw the following message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: ext\\curl (The specified module could not be found), ext\\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: ext\\mbstring (The specified module could not be found), ext\\php_mbstring.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: ext\\openssl (The specified module could not be found), ext\\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

The installation paths are: 
c:\Webserver\Apache24

c:\Webserver\php

At first I thought of a permission problem, so I open the hole directory of "Webserver" to "everyone" with "full access", but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Write full path for `extension_dir`. Do you have these extensions' DLLs inside `ext` dir?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the problem. After I added the path of the PHP folder to the Windows environment variables and restart windows, the error message was gone.